# SQL XML list of nodes separated by comma

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltable

I have a normal SQL table, one of the column is an XML, example:

```
...
<Element><id>first</id></Element>
<Element><id>second</id></Element>
...
```

I need to get the list of id's separated by commas:

```
id_list
---
first,second
```

For now, I have achieved it creating an XMLTABLE with the ids:

```
id
----
first
second
```

and then using the LISTAGG function of Oracle.
I wonder if exist some function/loop (maybe FLWOR?) to get the same result but not converting the XML input to an XMLTABLE.

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Why? The way you are doing it now is the "natural" or "normal" way to do it; why do you want to do it some other way? This could be done, for example, using text manipulation (regular expression functions), but **why** do it that way?

Comment: I could do it concatenating values like this: REPLACE( TRIM(extractvalue(xmltype(xml_input), '/Element[1]/id') || ' ' || .. || extractvalue(xmltype(xml_input), '/Element[n]/id')) , ' ', ',') but the max number of elements - n - could vary. I would like to reduce the processing of Oracle to get the query faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you must, you could do something like what I show in the query below.

However, I don't view this as a good approach; what you are doing currently, by creating an XML table and then using `LISTAGG`, seems better.

```
with inputs ( xml_str ) as (
       select '...
               <Element><id>first</id></Element>
               <Element><id>second</id></Element>
               ...'
       from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution); SQL query begins below this line
select rtrim( regexp_replace( xml_str, '.*?(<Element><id>(.*?)</id></Element>|$)'
                            , '\2,', 1, 0, 'n')
            , ',') as id_list
from   inputs
;



ID_LIST
------------
first,second
```

Comment: Thanks, the xml input that I put as example is not the actual xml to precess, so I think that the regexp_replace would become more complicated

Comment: @LucaDiGregorio - I agree! Do what you are doing right now, or what Alex has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could so it just within the XMLDB function, with [XPath `string-join` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join).

As an XMLQuery if you have a single value to process (with your sample data provided via a CTE and a dummy root node):

```
with t (xml) as (
  select xmltype('<root>
<Element><id>first</id></Element>
<Element><id>second</id></Element>
</root>') from dual
)
select xmlquery('
  for $i in /root
    return <e>{ fn:string-join($i/Element/id, ",") }</e>/text()'
  passing xml
  returning content
) as result
from t;

RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
first,second
```

Or with an XMLTable:

```
with t (xml) as (
  select xmltype('<root>
<Element><id>first</id></Element>
<Element><id>second</id></Element>
</root>') from dual
)
select x.*
from t
cross join xmltable('
  for $i in /root
    return <e>{ fn:string-join($i/Element/id, ",") }</e>'
  passing xml
  columns result varchar2(4000) path '.'
) x;

RESULT                                                                          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
first,second
```

I'm not sure there's much advantage in doing that over `listagg()`, but might be interesting to compare the performance of both with your real data, particularly if there are a lot of nodes. Except, by changing the XMLTable column type to CLOB, you can get a larger value out of that version that you can with `listagg()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use something like this for my purpose: select x.RESULT
from xmltable('
  for $i in /root
    return <dummy>{ fn:string-join($i/Element/id, ",") }</dummy>'
  passing xmltype('<root>
<Element><id>first</id></Element>
<Element><id>second</id></Element>
</root>
')
  columns result varchar2(4000) path '/dummy'
) x;