# XMLTABLE Returning Null for Single & Multiple Lookups

Tags: xml, oracle, parsing, extract, xmltable

I've done extensive searches on here for similar inquires regarding parsing XML fields which are expected to return 1 or more of the same tags. I've tried to export at least one record before bothering to attempt the parsing of multiple rows however it still returns Null.

At this point, I'm completely baffled at why this is happening.

**Example XML from column name "XMLPref":**

```
<ParentProfiler>
  <SettingExp>
    <Entity name="companycode" type="robot" value="fn8ks92in"></Entity>
    <Entity name="locationcode" type="dummy" value="CO"></Entity>
    <Entity name="companycode" type="dummy" value="0xm9n4mdk"></Entity>
  </SettingExp>
</ParentProfiler>
```

I'm trying to parse all `<Entity>` tags with `name = "companycode"` and retrieve the value associated with them. A few other XMLs are quite large so I've simplified the XML above to only three entities.

My testing query below is an attempt at using the old `extractvalue(xmltype` method and `XMLTABLE` method.

**Test Query:**

```
select z.test1, z.test2, b.XMLPref 
,extractvalue(xmltype(b.XMLPref),'//ParentProfiler/SettingExp/Entity[@name="companycode"]/@value[0]') as TestingOldMethod
from test.XMLTABLE b,
XMLTABLE('/ParentProfiler/SettingExp'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(b.XMLPref)
    COLUMNS test1  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'Entity[@name="companycode"]/text()' --'Entity/text()'
           ,test2  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH 'Entity[1]' -- 'Values/string-join(./Entity/text(), ",")',
    ) z
```

After attempting different variations of the path, whether it's one single parse (first iteration) or multiple, NULL is returned. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go down to the (filtered) `Entity` node in your XPath, and then get the `value` attributes from those:

```sql
XMLTABLE(
  '/ParentProfiler/SettingExp/Entity[@name="companycode"]'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(b.XMLPref)
  COLUMNS value  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH '@value'
)
```

As an example, keeping your confusing `xmltable` table name:

```sql
select x.value
from xmltable b
cross apply XMLTABLE(
  '/ParentProfiler/SettingExp/Entity[@name="companycode"]'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(b.XMLPref)
  COLUMNS value  VARCHAR2(100)  PATH '@value'
) x
```

| VALUE |
| --- |
| fn8ks92in |
| 0xm9n4mdk |

You can then easily get other attributes if you want:

```sql
select x.type, x.value
from xmltable b
cross apply XMLTABLE(
  '/ParentProfiler/SettingExp/Entity[@name="companycode"]'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(b.XMLPref)
  COLUMNS type VARCHAR2(100) PATH '@type',
    value VARCHAR2(100) PATH '@value'
) x
```

| TYPE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| robot | fn8ks92in |
| dummy | 0xm9n4mdk |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rnH8ye0Y)

---

Your `extractvalue` would sort of work if looked for a specific instance of the `Entity` rather than `value`, and indexed as 1 not 0, i.e.:

```
'/ParentProfiler/SettingExp/Entity[@name="companycode"][1]/@value'
```

but that only gets you one value, and is deprecated of course.

Your XMLTable version is looking for the text content of the `Entity` node, which is indeed null, rather than the `value` attribute, but has other problems in that form too.

Comment: Fantastic! It worked for the first found entry in each row respectively however I'm looking to include all instances of that field. I've tried to follow your other post for multiple entries (in comma delimited form): https://stackoverflow.com/a/43716441/3550594 but it's not working in my case. I see the comma delimited results without any value (ex: ", , , , ,):

`'for $i in /ParentProfiler/SettingExp/
    return <e>{ fn:string-join($i/Entity[@name="companycode"], ",") }</e>/text()'`

I also laughed at the "confusing xmltable name" as I realized that after naming it for simplistic terms.

Comment: Disregard! I think I figured it out... I missed the `@value`! `'for $i in /ParentProfiler/SettingExp/     return <e>{ fn:string-join($i/Entity[@name="companycode"]/@value, ",") }</e>'`  Taking a break sure does help! Thank you so much for your input, Alex! Now I will try to see if I can unpivot these comma delimited fields into multiple rows. Hah!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You shouldn't need to aggregate and then deconstruct. This approach works with multiple rows and/or rows with multiple `SettingExp` nodes - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M6BxIZQE) - so I don't know what you are seeing, or trying to do. Maybe ask a new question with a more representative XML document and the result you're trying to achieve for that.